# How to focus manually with a Nikkor AF-S DX VR 50-200mm f/4-5.6G zoom lens?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, focus, zoom

I have a Nikon D3100, for which I just bought a Nikkor AF-S DX VR 50-200mm f/4-5.6G zoom lens. This is a CPU lens and works very nicely in auto-mode, i.e. when you let the camera set the focus.

However, I want to also sometimes manually pull focus. How do I do that with this lens? It seems that it is missing the focus ring.

Is it not possible to set focus manually with this lens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the following diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Move the focus switch on the lens barrel to the MF position. You will now be able to focus by rotating the front-most part of the lens barrel.

Comment: Yes, there is an A-M switch and I do set it to M when I use my other lenses. The problem is -- I can't find a focus ring on this lens.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - It's a barely-visible hard plastic knurled ring right at the end of the lens. It's touchy, too - the tubes have a bit of play (wobble), so manual focus at longer focal lengths isn't easy.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 `You will now be able to focus by rotating the front-most part of the lens barrel.` Judging by the [Wikipedia image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_AF-S_DX_Zoom-Nikkor_55-200mm_f/4-5.6G#mediaviewer/File:Nikon_DX_AF-S_55-200mm_VR.jpg) it's the part highlighted here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt8Uy.png You could confirm this by turning the lens back to AF and see which parts move while it tries to focus.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it tomorrow and report back. I've packed it away and it is night just now. I did notice this ring and tried fiddling with it while it was in auto-focus but only briefly as I feared I might damage the lens. I'll try again tomorrow. Thank you.